# Android - AsyncTask onProgressUpdate called but not "as expected"?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

With yet another question, Here I come. Using an Async task as follows:

```
private class ProcessFileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Void>{
        String fileName;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String[] splitData;
        byte[] currentArray;
        ByteBuffer bb;

        public ProcessFileTask(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            currentArray = new byte[19];
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                splitData = bufferedReader.readLine().split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i += 19) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
                        currentArray[j] = Byte.parseByte(splitData[i+j]);

                    }
                    publishProgress(currentArray);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Exception occured", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            bb.put(values[0], 1, 18);
            ChannelOne.updateGraph(bb.getShort(0), bb.getShort(2), bb.getShort(4));
            ChannelTwo.updateGraph(bb.getShort(12), bb.getShort(14), bb.getShort(16));

        }
    }
```

At this part of execution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i += 19) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
        currentArray[j] = Byte.parseByte(splitData[i+j]);
    }
    publishProgress(currentArray);
}
```

I expect the publishProgress to be called everytime the 'i' loop executes. While that happens(which was verified by Logging data), the code in onProgressUpdate() does not get executed properly(which is evident because the result of updateGraph can be seen only after the AsyncTask ends. Also, the end graph is completely mis-formed(the graph shows mostly straight lines while it must be curves).

This strange problem does not occur, if the whole code is run directly on UI Thread and the graph is rendered perfectly. In that case, as you know, the UI gets blocked for a few seconds.

I tried, instead of AsyncTask running the code as an individual thread but the same results persist. Any workarounds can be made? Can a service be used in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18944439/793943 check on this

Comment: @sush The OP there said the onProgressUpdate() never got called, and further went on to solve his own problem by using '@Override'. However, my problem is different. Here, onProgressUpdate() is called, but the UI updates are not done properly.

Comment: It has ur ans too.. read -
The timing of the execution is undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.

Comment: @sush If onProgressUpdate() does not get immediately called after publishProgress(), can runOnUiThread() be used in doInBackground()? Doing so gives same wrong graph as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing "super.onProgressUpdate(values);" from your code

```
 @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
        bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        bb.put(values[0], 1, 18);
        ChannelOne.updateGraph(bb.getShort(0), bb.getShort(2), bb.getShort(4));
        ChannelTwo.updateGraph(bb.getShort(12), bb.getShort(14), bb.getShort(16));

    }
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that did not work and the results are the same as before :(